# Network drive: "Size on disk" multiples of 128MB instead of reality

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, ntfs, network-drive

I've had a Buffalo LS420D 4TB NTFS network drive for years (no special setup - just whatever was the default as far as I can remember), but I just now noticed that no matter how small a file actually is, if I right-click on it and choose Properties, the "Size on disk" claims to be 128MB! I searched around and found a file whose real size was slightly bigger than that, and yup, the "Size on disk" for that one jumped to 256MB. (Command line `dir` reports the same as the "Size" line in Properties.) Curious how far the absurdity would go, I asked for the Properties on the folder I know has the most files - an old but massive clipart collection. I had to let it run overnight, but yup, it was pretty hilarious - 76TB! Below are screenshots of the craziness. I'm viewing it with Windows 10 64-bit, if that matters. What's going on?

[image: Tiny test file]

[image: Directory of many small files]

***Additional info in response to multiple comments:***

- My NAS drive's firmware is already on the most current version (1.81). I apparently bought the drive more recently than I thought, because that version was released June 2015.
- I don't know how to determine the NTFS cluster size, but [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/140365/default-cluster-size-for-ntfs,-fat,-and-exfat) seems to say that the default would be 4kB, and I'm pretty sure I didn't deviate from that (I don't even know how). But if you want me to check directly, please tell me how, because googling did not reveal such instruction. (`chkdsk`: "Windows cannot check a disk attached through a network." `fsutil`: "The FSUTIL utility requires a local NTFS volume.")
- At Larssend's insistence I installed Wireshark and saved a brief capture during which I viewed Properties on my 3-byte `text.txt` and then opened the same file in Notepad. I have no idea how to interpret the log of interactions, so I have uploaded it as [binary Wireshark file](http://proverbs2525.org/temp/small-file-on-nas.pcapng) and [exported plain text](http://proverbs2525.org/temp/wireshark.txt). `192.168.1.8` is my PC and `192.168.1.23` is the NAS drive (192.168.1.19 is my printer, which was idle - I'm not sure why there was chatter with that).

I considered connecting via USB to see if it acted the same way, but I don't have the right cable - the drive's USB jack is Type-A (thin rectangle) instead of the expected Type-B (square with two angled corners), and I don't have a cable with Type-A on both ends.

Comment: It looks like your Art folder has...exploded

Comment: What software is serving that share. Could be a problem on the server side. Some NAS systems are not that compatible with Windows Servers.

Comment: Capture your network using Wireshark while accessing `test.txt` and analyze the capture data. Close other network/Internet programs before starting the capture to minimize noise.This will help you verify the source of the problem (either your NAS or Windows). I suspect your NAS is to blame for reporting the wrong allocation size.

Comment: Can you tell more about the specification / configuration of your "4TB NTFS network drive"?

Comment: @KennethL: It's a Buffalo LS420D, with nothing special done to it. I added that to the question above.

Comment: @eckes: I have no idea what software it is - I simply bought a big hard drive (Buffalo LS420D) and followed the instructions to get it started. By the way, I don't have Windows Server - just a couple Windows PCs on a little home network. And although the drive is capable of NAS from afar, I have never set it up to do that - we only access it on our local LAN.

Comment: It might be running RAID 1, because my memory tells me that I bought an 8TB drive, but I only see 3.62TB of storage (1.34TB of it in use). Since we probably had less than 1TB of stuff to put on it at the time, that would have made sense - use the extra space as self-backup until we fill it up.

Comment: Have you updated your Nas in a while?

Comment: Seems to be a known 'problem' https://community.netgear.com/t5/Using-your-ReadyNAS/Size-of-files-folders-vs-quot-size-on-disk-quot-MASSIVELY/td-p/856445

Comment: "updated your Nas" - I'm not sure what that entails. From what I understand, NAS is the capability to be a server with authentication from the web on some open port - I have never used that technology on this or any other drive. To me this is just a hard drive that I can access by LAN rather than just USB. I've never "updated" a hard drive. Am I missing something?

Comment: @eckes: Yeah, I saw that post when I was googling initially. But his problem was caused by isolated files being out of whack (and possibly also some issue with a bug in a certain version of Windows 8.1, which has never touched this drive - we jumped from Win7 straight to 10). My file size of 128MB is consistent, for every file.

Comment: NAS means an appliance which makes storage available on the network (including your LAN). Your NAS has a firmware and according to the discussion I linked it might fix that problem in a later version.

Comment: Just use Wireshark already. Upload your capture file somewhere and link to it in your post if you need help with analyzing it.

Comment: what is the NTFS cluster size of the drive?

Comment: @Larssend and others: See additional info in my post in response to your questions and suggestions.

Comment: over network the files are transferred using samba or CIFS so it doesn't know anything about the file system like NTFS or ext4. Even if you use ext4 in the NAS HDD Windows can still see it without problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your Wireshark capture file, in packet no. 17:

```
QUERY_PATH_INFO Data
    Allocation Size: 134217728
    End Of File: 3
    Link Count: 1
    Delete Pending: Normal, no pending delete (0)
    Is Directory: This is NOT a directory (0)
    Unknown Data: 0000
```

Your NAS is reporting 134217728 bytes, which equals to 128MB assuming 1024 bytes in 1 KB, of allocated size (or 'size on disk') for `test.txt`. So the problem is on your NAS side. The obvious solution is to update the firmware and/or operating system on your NAS (assuming there is any such update available). If there is no update available, you will have to report the bug to the vendor (Buffalo).

Comment: The firmware is already current (version 1.81, released June 2015), and that model of drive appears to be out of production now, so I doubt that reporting it would cause them to make an update to firmware at this point. What sort of consequences could I run into by ignoring it?

Comment: @OsakaWebbie: I wouldn't know. I can't simulate this kind of problem, so I can't do any kind of testing.

Comment: I don't think this has any consequences besides you have imprecise sizing statistics

Comment: @Larssend: By the way, how in the world did you find that packet info? The text file is utterly useless (the number 134217728 does not appear at all), and in Wireshark I was only able to find what you posted by clicking on #17 and drilling down several layers in the lower pane (Frame 17... -> SMB -> Trans2 Response (0x32) -> QUERY_PATH_INFO Data). There were almost 900 packets in that log, and a lot of layers of data in each one - how did you know what to look for and where to look?

Comment: @OsakaWebbie: in Wireshark, click packet no. 17, then in the middle pane, expand `SMB (Server Message Block Protocol)` > `Trans2 Response` > `QUERY_PATH_INFO_DATA`.

Comment: Yes, I know that now (if you read my previous comment carefully you'll see that I did exactly that), but my question was how you initially figured out that packet #17 out of 800+ would have something relevant.

Comment: @OsakaWebbie: I know the protocol a little bit. I'm not an expert, but I know, in principle, how the SMB protocol works.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I guess the cause of the crazy size will have to remain a mystery. I expected it to be something common that others recognized and could explain, but apparently it's a weird quirk or rare bug.